# "Необязательно": слитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не

В данном случае *необязательно* пишется слитно или раздельно?

*Оставьте свой комментарий (необязательно, но так мы поймем, какие темы вас интересуют больше).*

Answer (score 1):

**Правильно:**

*Оставьте свой комментарий (**необязательно**, но так мы поймем, какие темы вас интересуют больше).*

**Пояснение**

1. Необязательно в значении **сказуемого**: *Это **необязательно*** (нет необходимости).
2. Возможны **обе формы** написания, что можно проверить **по словарю.**

Выбираем **утвердительную** форму, так как нет оснований для отрицания. **При отрицании** тема должна быть заданной в контексте, или отрицание логически подчеркивается.

**Сравнить:** — Оставлять комментарий обязательно? — Нет, не обязательно.

**Нацкорпус**

**1. Утверждение**

— **Необязательно** расспрашивать самому, достаточно подготовить почву для моего появления.Вера Белоусова. Второй выстрел (2000)

Можно подумать, что любовь — это одно, а способности — другое и им **необязательно** совпадать. Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)

— Хорошая история **необязательно** должна быть истинной, достаточно правдоподобия, — повторял Зубр слова Нильса Бора. — Нужно ли слишком строго следовать за фактами?" Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)

**2. Отрицание**

А картины существуют только для того, чтобы вешать их на стену.
Смотреть — **не обязательно**. Токарева Виктория. Своя правда // «Новый Мир», 2002

— Чтобы узнать что-то от человека, **не обязательно** его видеть.

**Словари**

**Орфографический словарь**: необязательно, нареч. и в знач. сказ.

**Большой толковый словарь**

**НЕОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО,** нареч. 1. к Необязательный (3 зн.). Смежники вели себя крайне н. **2. в функц. сказ.** О том, что не является обязательным, непременным; **нет необходимости**. Вам н. приезжать самому. Ему н. лечиться в санатории. Н., чтобы об этом все знали.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, не обязательно - это предикативное наречие типа "не надо, не нужно, не жаль" и тп, с которыми частица НЕ- всегда пишется раздельно. Так же и в предложенной фразе

Comment: 1) https://russkiypro.ru/pravilnoe-pravopisanie-nenuzhno-ili-ne-nuzhno/ 2) http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=необязательно&all=x